# Passing carriage return to SQL SP through C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, carriage-return

I have a c# program that calls a SQL Stored proc, and passes some strings to it, e.g.

```
string str1 = "Some String 1";
string str1 = "Some String 2";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(MySP, conn)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        }
        )
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Par1", str1);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Par2", str2);
    conn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Now I would like to add a carriage return into str1.
But adding it like default (str1 = "Some \r\n string";) does not send the carriage return to SQL, but it sends the full string with the escape characters.

How else can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you checking that the carriage return is missing in the database?

Comment: The stored proc sends an email, and the specific text in the email does not have a carriage return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Environment.NewLine`:

```
string str1 = "Some" + Environment.NewLine + "String";
```