# Passing a string with \r to sql stored proc in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm populating a model in an mvc controller, the model has a public string of Name which is to capture the AD name of the users using the web app.

in the controller in debug model.Name has the right value.  So something like DOMAIN\rjones.

the problem is if a user has an initial of r or n then the \r or \n (maybe other chars) are getting stripped out.

I'm passing the values to sql by the following:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dev.uspCreateNewDevCase @LoggedBy, @LoggedFor, @ShortDescription, @LongDescription, @DateDue"
                                            , new SqlParameter("@LoggedBy", model.Name )
                                            , new SqlParameter("@LoggedFor", model.LoggedFor)
                                            , new SqlParameter("@ShortDescription", model.ShortDescription)
                                            , new SqlParameter("@LongDescription", model.LongDescription)
                                            , new SqlParameter("@DateDue", model.DateDue)
```

in debug, the model.Name `, new SqlParameter("@LoggedBy", model.Name )` has the correct string text.

I have stripped the stored procedure down in sql to just write that value to a table, and when I query the table it has the value of DOMAIN jones the \r has been taken out.

As mentioned this is dynamic as in it will depend on the user using the app if they have an r or n in the name.  Is there a way to encode this or preserve it so when it passed to SQL it maintains the \r or \n.

I'm assuming it is being lost in C# as in T-SQL you can store that value in a variable and insert it into a table.  The T-sql data type is NVARCHAR

fixed

I was passing the value to the controller by an Ajax method of:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlAction,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Name: @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name ,
```

However, I have set the model value in the view via @Html.HiddenFor to be $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlAction,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Name: @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name , which passes the value with a \ in it and then writes correctly to the SQL table.

Comment: `MyString = @"DOMAIN\rjones";`?

Comment: The string has the correct value at that point

Comment: "seems to strip it out when passing it to the proc" - how did you determine that?

Comment: when i run the app in debug, the MyString has the value, but when the proc is run, i have stripped it down now to just insert that var into a table it does it without the \r.  I'm not sure if it is Sql ot c# or both but i do know in sql you can pass a variable the value of \r and store it in a  table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing carriage return to SQL SP through C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540471/passing-carriage-return-to-sql-sp-through-c-sharp)

Comment: "it does it without the \r" - how did you determine that? Did you read the value from the database and compared with `MyString`?

Comment: Yes, I stripped the stored procedure down to just insert the variable value into a table and it is there without the \r

Comment: Hi Owen,  not really a duplication, I'm looking for a way of keeping a value not forcing one in, also this would cater for the issue if a name was \n or another similar issue

Comment: oh boy, "it is there without the \r" - how did you determine that?

Comment: Igor, there is no need for a comment like oh boy, I said I inserted the value into a table, you asked if i read the database and compared i said yes. This was done directly in SSMS with a select statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a variable this way:

```
string myString="This is\rmy text"; -> "This is" + (char)13 + "my text"
```

It will be stored with a replace of `\r` as `(char)13` (that means the ASCII code CR for Carriage Return)

If you double the `\` it won't

```
string myString="This is\\rmy text"; -> "This is\rmy text"
```

Another general way is to start the string with the "at"-sign:

```
string myString=@"This is\rmy text"; -> "This is\rmy text"
```

Are you sure, that the variable contains the right value before you pass it?

EDIT:
What you see might not be what is there. Look at this:

[image: CarriageReturn on mouse hovering]

The preview on mouse hover shows the `\r` sign, but if you click the lense you get:

[image: CarriageReturn in real text]

So: please check again, if you really have what you think that you have...

Comment: Thanks for replying.  The issue is the value is coming from the model.  there will be times when it is different other user, DOMIAN\shnugo would be fine/  Yep, I have run in debug and the MyString 100% has the right text.  It then goes wayward but i can't see specifically what or where that point is as the next step is posting the proc

Comment: The only thing I can think of is replacing the \ with something that would change, a £ sign or something and then replacing back in sql

Comment: Please try to set your variable in debug mode to different values and look what happens. It could help to avoid the unwanted escaping by doubling the doubling. That would mean something like `This is\\\\rmy text`

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully it will make more sense.  I can't change the string value as it just looks at the users domain name

Comment: If i string MyVar =@"domain\rjones" it converts it to domain\\rjones and then when passed into the proc it is writing correctly to the rable with just the 1 backslash.  Is there a way to do this to the model value?

Comment: @JQuery, please look at the edit I've done. Are you really sure, that you have what you think to have?

Comment: It's working now, I passed it from the view differently and it works.  Have added to the question

Comment: Thank you for your help though, also the edit is good to know, I'll keep that in mind next time i see something that may not be there :)

Comment: @JQuery, glad to read that you could solve your problem... If my answer was usefull please vote it up and maybe mark as accepted, thx!